# What's the use of "else" at the end of a for or while block in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I already have a lot of experience in *Python*, but recently I've seen some people using `else` at the end of a `while` or `for` block. I was very curious and decided to test:

```
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
else:
    print("Something...")
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
Something...
```

Using or not else, the code will execute the same way, so what's the use of this?

Comment: You can read about that [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Answer (score 3):

`else` after a `for` or `while` block will execute if and only if the block terminates normally.  If you leave through a `break` or exception, that `else` block gets skipped.

```
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
    break
else:
    print("Something...")
```

Output:

```
0
```